What is this figuration?
I really struggle with breaking down compositions into their chords. I've studied different forms of figuration to help me with this.
However in the 1st bar of the attached piece of music I can't work out what that G (3rd note in the treble clef) is functioning as. Is it an arpeggiation?
I assume the chord for the bar is Am due to the bass notes A C E but then it looks like a C chord in the treble clef when you combine the 3 notes C E G. Which is it?
Can someone please help clarify what's going on?
Thank you
(And Happy New Year!)


@Tim this is the 3rd bar with the chord going back to Am again


You're correct, the 1st bar is Am. Then the 2nd has a Dm chord in the bass.
The G turns that Am into Am7 - leading nicely into that Dm.
